# create object with the specified variables only

Tags: java, object

I have an java class like below. So I want to make a object of that class with lesser variables.

```
public class ABC{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
}
```

So I want to make a object containing firstName only. Can I achieve this?? Or is there any way around as I need to create object with same or different number of variables.

Comment: just use this one, since you don't have a constructor, there's nothing that forces you to provide a lastname

Comment: Sounds like a bad abstraction to me.

Comment: @Stultuske this won't work as I am trying to store the excel datas where sometimes I get fields firstname and lastname sometimes more than 2 fields . So I need to make the objects according to the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inheritance here, like:

```
public class Base {
  private final String lastName;

  public Base(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
}

public class Child extends Base {
  private String firstName;

  public Child(String lastName, String firstName) { 
    super(lastName);
    this.firstName = firstName; 
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
}
```

Now, your base class has just one field, and the child class adds another one.

Given the comments by the OP: the straight forward answer here - use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You can use the "field names" from your excel file as keys within a map, and use the excel field values as map values. You can't have classes in Java that have "real" fields dynamically. The structure of a class is fixed - all fields are known at compile time. So, unless you want to create a class that knows all possible fields, the best thing would be to use a map.

Comment: Thanks.But this won't work as I am trying to store the excel datas where sometimes I get fields firstname and lastname sometimes more than 2 fields . So I need to make the objects according to the fields

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible. You could extend class ABC and override getLastname()

After Reading your comment, I think you should create a class for your dataobject that contains all the necessary fields and if there's a value in excel-file you set it if not then the value for that field is null.

Comment: I can't override as I won't know which fields are only comming during the import of excel file

Comment: You could create a class that has e.g. methods like Object getFieldvalue(String fieldname)  and setFieldvalue(String fieldname, Object value). And you store the values in some kind of map.